# .XNB file reader

Tags: xna, file

I'd like to open an XNB file on Linux.

It should be an `XNA Game Studio Express XNA Framework Content Pipeline Binary File`.

Any tool to open it? (also for windows which I can emulate on wine)

Comment: XNB files are just binary data with a special header that are readen by a game programmed with XNA. Why would you want to open them? And what do you want to do with the contents?

Comment: I've got an XNB file containing some images which I'd like to extract.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [GXView](http://gruaz.net/?page_id=407) program inside Gametools Suite should do the work, although I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: Note that XNB files are the result of the content pipeline processor. These can be custom made by the creator of a game. Thus there is not a generic XNB filereader. This tool probably implements the formats as supplied with the framework, so it most likely works for png, jpg, etc.